# Distance between two 3D vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Find the distance between the lines
${v} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} t$
and
${w} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} u.$

The distance between two lines is the smallest possible value of $PQ$, where $P$ is a point on one line and $Q$ is a point on the other line.

I know that these lines are skew, it's just that I can't find the shortest distance between the two lines and where they are.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330610/find-the-distance-between-the-lines-v-1-2-4-1-3-1t-and-w-0-3-5/1330633#1330633.

Comment: @Rory Oh, thanks, I miscalculated it... I think the answer can be obtained analytically.

Answer (score 2):

For $P = (1 - t, 2 + 3t, -4 - t), Q = (u, 3 + 4u, 5 + 3u)$, 
$$d(P, Q) = \sqrt{(1 - t - u)^2 + (-1 + 3t - 4u)^2 + (-9 - t - 3u)^2}$$
To minimize $d(P, Q)$, it is equivalent to minimize $f(t, u) = d(P, Q)^2$.
The necessary condition for local minimum is $\nabla f(t, u) = 0$. Solve this system, we get $(t_0, u_0) = \left(-\frac{37}{17}, -\frac{31}{71}\right)$. Also, you can check the Hessian matrix is positive definite, so it is indeed a minimum. In addition, the objective function is convex, so it is also a global minimum.

Comment: Looks good to me.